# How to boot Mac from CD from verbose command line

Tags: startup, powerbook

So already I've tried booting Ubuntu on a USB from the Mac's command line (verboes or something like that). But it didn't seem to work at all and said load size is too small or came up with a no entry symbol.

So I put a Ubuntu 32 bit on a CD and now I don't know how to boot it. I can't open up the boot menu as all of the important drivers are gone from the computer.

Comment: Please add your Mac model. Are you really using a PowerBook? The last PB was discontinued in April, 2006!

Comment: @klanomath yes i am, i got it from someone else actually

Answer (score 1):

Mac hardware will always boot to an os chooser holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key. You of course need a USB / thunderbolt / FireWire drive with bootable media at that point.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Newer Macs use internet recovery to net boot and from there you can repartition any drives and reinstall all drivers needed to boot macOS and start again.

- [Accessing Internet Recovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223684/accessing-internet-recovery)

For a PowerBook, you might also use cd / DVD media since internet recovery isn't an option for PPC hardware.

Comment: it wont detect the externel drive

Comment: You might want to check out a Ubuntu specific forum, there may be more to booting Ubuntu on a Mac than just a general purpose liveCD/Installer. If it does not detect the drive it may just be that does not have anything on it in the way of needful boot software. If you boot macOS does it see the drive in Disk Utility? Remember that macOS is won't access EXT formatted drives without special software.